# How to set a specific number of slidesperview using swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I am trying to fix the maximum number of visible slides per view. I am using Swiper. This is my jsx code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/effect-coverflow';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';

import { EffectCoverflow, Pagination, Navigation } from 'swiper';

import slide_image_1 from './assets/images/img_1.jpg';
import slide_image_2 from './assets/images/img_2.jpg';
import slide_image_3 from './assets/images/img_3.jpg';
import slide_image_4 from './assets/images/img_4.jpg';
import slide_image_5 from './assets/images/img_5.jpg';
import slide_image_6 from './assets/images/img_6.jpg';
import slide_image_7 from './assets/images/img_7.jpg';

function App() {

  const slides = [
    slide_image_1,
    slide_image_2,
    slide_image_3,
    slide_image_4,
    slide_image_5,
    slide_image_6,
    slide_image_7,
  ];


  const renderSlides = () =>
    slides.map((slide, index) => (
      <SwiperSlide key={index}>
        <img src={slide} alt={`slide_image_${index}`} />
      </SwiperSlide>
    ));

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Swiper
        effect={'coverflow'}
        grabCursor={true}
        slideToClickedSlide={true}
        centeredSlides={true}
        loop={true}
        slidesPerView={{
          number: 3,
        }}
        coverflowEffect={{
          rotate: 0,
          stretch: 0,
          depth: 100,
          modifier: 2.5,
        }}

        modules={[EffectCoverflow, Pagination, Navigation]}
        className="swiper_container"
      >

        {renderSlides()}
        {renderSlides()}



        <div className="slider-controler">
        </div>
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

css code

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
}

:root {
  --primary: #6a59ff;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --bg: #f5f5f5;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  html {
    zoom: 1.5;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 2560px) {
  html {
    zoom: 1.7;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 3860px) {
  html {
    zoom: 2.5;
  }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1.3rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: #797979;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #222224;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background: var(--bg);
}

.container {
  max-width: 124rem;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.heading {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper_container {
  height: 52rem;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-slide {
  width: 37rem;
  height: 42rem;
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .swiper_container {
    height: 47rem;
  }
  .swiper-slide {
    width: 28rem !important;
    height: 36rem !important;
  }
  .swiper-slide img {
    width: 28rem !important;
    height: 36rem !important;
  }
}

.swiper-slide img {
  width: 37rem;
  height: 42rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  display: none;
}

.slider-controler {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider-controler .swiper-button-next {
  left: 58% !important;
  transform: translateX(-58%) !important;
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .slider-controler .swiper-button-next {
    left: 70% !important;
    transform: translateX(-70%) !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .slider-controler .swiper-button-next {
    left: 80% !important;
    transform: translateX(-80%) !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .slider-controler .swiper-button-prev {
    left: 30% !important;
    transform: translateX(-30%) !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .slider-controler .swiper-button-prev {
    left: 20% !important;
    transform: translateX(-20%) !important;
  }
}

.slider-controler .slider-arrow {
  background: var(--white);
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 42%;
  transform: translateX(-42%);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 24px rgba(18, 28, 53, 0.1));
}

.slider-controler .slider-arrow ion-icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #222224;
}

.slider-controler .slider-arrow::after {
  content: '';
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: relative;
  width: 15rem !important;
  bottom: 1rem;
}

.swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 8px 24px rgba(18, 28, 53, 0.1));
}

.swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: var(--primary);
}
```

and html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>3d Slider</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      type="module"
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      nomodule
      src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use

```
slidesPerView={{
          number: 3,
        }}
```

I used before slidesPerView ={'auto'}, which gives me the same result. Could you please help me out? Btw, I want to implement afterwords this swiper in a container in a website. If it needs a different solution let me know. ps I am no expert. I searched and tried to implement solutions of people that experienced a similar problem with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I changed slidesPerView={'auto}
and played with the slides opacity in the CSS file.

```css
.swiper-slide {
  width: 22rem;
  height: 100%;
  position: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-slide-prev {
  opacity: 1; /* Show center, left, and right slides */
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

If you set the opacity off all slides to 0 and then edit the centre, prev (left), and next (right) slides opacity to 1, you get the desired effect. The pointer-event globally to 0 and for the centre, left, and right slide to all avoids the possibility of clicking on the invisible slides.